# jquery var define only first element

Tags: jquery, html, variables

I have a problem with jquery var and i'm so confused..
I make a var due to variable "id" but it affect only on the first element:

jQuery:

```
var butInfo = $(".but > div").attr("id");

$("#" + butInfo).each(function(){
    $(this)
        .mouseenter(function(){
            $(".txt").hide();
            $(".txt."+butInfo).show();})
        .mouseleave(function(){
            $(".txt."+butInfo).hide();});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="but">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="b">B</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
<div class="txt a">A A A A A</div>
<div class="txt b">B B B B B</div>
<div class="txt c">C C C C C</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74FYW/

as you see, only the first `div` with `id="a"` is working, while the rest is still not working..
why that happened?!!

**UPDATE:**
**==========**
I found finally what I want.
the solution simply is to put the `var` line after jquery function not before it;

this is what I mean:

```
$(".but > div").each(function(){
  var butInfo = $(this).attr("id"); 
  $(this)
    .mouseenter(function(){
      $(".txt").hide();
      $(".txt."+butInfo).show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
      $(".txt."+butInfo).hide();
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/74FYW/4/)

Answer (score 3):

[`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) gets an attribute of the first element from the matched collection. Try something like this instead:

```
var $txt = $(".txt").hide();
$(".but > div").mouseenter(function() {
    $txt.hide().filter('.' + this.id).show();
})
.mouseleave(function () {
    $txt.hide();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/74FYW/1/

Comment: Great! thanks..
but is there another way without using filter? cuz in my original code i use multiple selector not only .txt

Comment: you can get based on index value

Answer (score 0):

you can use this but it is not prefferable way

```
     $(".but > div").mouseenter(function() {
            var index=$('.but div').index(this);
            $('.txt:eq('+index+')').show();
        }).mouseleave(function () {
    $('.txt').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks, but this way depends on the sequencing not on id

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, but i found finally what I want.
the solution simply is to put the var line inside the jquery function not before it;

this is what I mean:

```
$(".but > div").each(function(){
  var butInfo = $(this).attr("id"); 
  $(this)
    .mouseenter(function(){
      $(".txt").hide();
      $(".txt."+butInfo).show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
      $(".txt."+butInfo).hide();
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/74FYW/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.value > '0') {
var ya1 = $('#' + this.value + 'yap1').val();
$('#yap1').val(ya1);
```

Comment: Please give a brief explanation fo what your code does and why it helps to answer the asker's question.

Comment: Also, I'm no `jQuery` expert, but it looks like you're missing a closing curly brace:  `}`